# how to access information about which dropdown item has been pressed by a user for a bootstrap dropdown reactjs

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

So I copied this bootstrap dropdowns into the return of my NavBar component in react. But i'm not sure how to actually use it, e.g. where do I place the handleChange function so that when an item has been selected from the dropdown, I can store the info of which item has been selected, inside my state variable:

```
import React from "react";
export default function Navbar({ state, handleChange }) {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
          Pathfinding Visualizer
        </a>
        <button
          className="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
          aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul className="navbar-nav">
            <li className="nav-item dropdown">
              <a
                className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                href="#"
                role="button"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Algorithms
              </a>
              <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    Depth-First Search
                  </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    Breadth-first Search
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    Dijkstra
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    A-star
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    Random Walk
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item dropdown">
              <a
                className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                href="#"
                role="button"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Mazes
              </a>
              <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    Recursive Division
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    Vertical
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    Horizontal
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    Random
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">
                Add Bomb
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                Visualise
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

I wanna be able to do something like this, but with my dropdown from bootstrap:

```
<select
        id="algoPicked"
        value={state.algoPicked}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="algoPicked"
      >
        <option value="red">Depth-First Search</option>
        <option value="orange">Breadth-First Search</option>
        <option value="yellow">A Star</option>
        <option value="green">Randomn Walk</option>
        <option value="blue">Dijikstra</option>
      </select>
```

I tried to put the variable inside of the 'a' tag like so, but obviously that doesent work

```
  <a
        className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
        href="#"
        role="button"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-expanded="false"

        // stuff I tried to add but doesent work

        id="algoPicked"
        value={state.algoPicked}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="algoPicked"
      ></a>
```

Comment: Can someone please tell me why (I assume) my question is difficult to understand?

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind! I've moved over to react-bootstrap now and it easily solves these queries with it's custom components.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).